# How to set an array to everything in multiple other arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

sorry if this is an amateur question, i'm still new to this.

```
        int[] ex1 = {1, 5, 6, 7 };
        int[] ex2 = {5, 6, 2, 6, 7, 5};
        int[] res = { ( everything from ex1 and ex2)};
```

I want "res" to be everything from ex1 AND ex2, without having to manually list each number from both arrays.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With LINQ:

```
var res = ex1.Concat(ex2).ToArray()
```